# How to select audio output in Raspberry 4

Tags: audio, pi-4

I have a youtube video playing in Chromium and I can hear the sound that comes from HDMI, to the built-in monitor speakers.

How can I select where the audio goes?
I'd like to hear the sound in the speakers connected to the audio jack.
I'm using Raspbian and in the audio preferences, there is no choice for audio output.

Comment: My answer and COMMENTS to the following similar question might help: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/100265/3-5-mm-jack-speakers-not-being-recognized

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Advanced Options in `raspi-config` has an option to select default audio output.

Right clicking on the speaker icon in the GUI also displays output options (including, in my case, Bluetooth).

Answer (score 0):

For posterity, this is no longer under Advanced, but under System Options > Audio